# Changing a button background colour using RGB

Tags: if-statement, xcode6, rgb, uicolor

Im sure that it will be a simple and obvious fix, but I cannot see why this occurs.

Basically I want to code a button to change its background colour, depending on what the colour is at the present. The following code works but it uses the UI Colours in xcode.

```
-(IBAction)Button1Colour:(id)sender{

if (_Button1.backgroundColor == nil) {
    _Button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];}

else if (_Button1.backgroundColor == [UIColor orangeColor]) {
    _Button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];}

else (_Button1.backgroundColor = nil);}
```

Now if I use RGB colours as follows:

```
-(IBAction)Button1Colour:(id)sender{

if (_Button1.backgroundColor == nil) {
    _Button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(216/255.f) green:(146/255.f) blue:(48/255.f) alpha:0.3];}

else if (_Button1.backgroundColor == [UIColor colorWithRed:(216/255.f) green:(146/255.f) blue:(48/255.f) alpha:0.3]) {
    _Button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(33/255.f) green:(141/255.f) blue:(8/255.f) alpha:0.3];}

else (_Button1.backgroundColor = nil);}
```

The button will only cycle from nil to amber to nil etc missing out the else if statement.

Any advice or help would be much appreciated

Comment: is any of your condition evaluates ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to determine whether the button is a particular color by comparing 3 sets of floating point numbers.

The second if test is failing because you can't compare `CGFloat`s for exact equality.

The easier way is to subclass your button and add a BOOL property indicating whether it's "toggled" or not.  Then you can check the property and simply change between one color and the next.

Assuming the property you add is called green, it would look like this

```
@property (assign, getter=isGreen) BOOL green;
```

and you could more concisely change the color like so

```
Button1.backgroundColor = [Button1 isGreen] ? [UIColor orangeColor] : [UIColor greenColor];
Button1.green = !Button1.green;
```

As an aside, naming conventions suggest that a class starts with a capital letter, e.g. `UIButton`.  An instance variable starts with a lowercase letter, e.g. `button1`.